# How to specify a default log4j2 configuration file in Ubuntu

Tags: xml, logging, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 for logging but I'm getting error messages only, which is I think default configs. I've created `log4j2.xml` as:

```c
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appenders>
   <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern=" %msg%n"/>
   </Console>
  </appenders>
   <loggers>
    <logger name="log4jExample" level="trace">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </logger>
   <root level="error">
     <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
   </root>
   </loggers>
 </configuration>
```

and mentioned its path in `CLASSPATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` file. But its still not picking this XML file. Do I've to mention config file at runtime only. `~/.bashrc` file contians:

```
 export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/user/Pradi/config/log4j2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Classpath configuration can vary a lot depending on your application. Is it a Java SE application? If your application is packaged in a jar file, you might define your Classpath in a META-INF file. If it's just a simple class your running from Console, you might try placing this log4j2.xml in the root of your package structure.

What's the folder structure you're using to run this class?

EDIT:
Usually config files are placed in different directories, but not entirely different folder structures. It's common to have a source folder like src/main/java and another one src/main/resources. After compilation, usually they place files in the same root folder, target/classes for example. In your simple test, I'd place the files in the same folder, and if you're running the class from /home/user/Pradi, the command would be "java -classpath /home/user/Pradi log4jExample". If you tell me how you're compiling your class, I can give you more guidance on how to organize these files.

Comment: yeah its simple class which is running from console. I'm using log4j2 for the first time, so just checking how it loggs. I placed the xml in root of package but still its not picking the file. Folder structure for running class is different from root package. For running class, it is /home/user/Pradi/log4jExample.java and for xml file /home/user/log4j2/apache-log4j-2.0-beta3-bin/log4j2.xml And its picking the xml file only when it is in the folder same as my .java file. but configs should be in different folder right?

Comment: [/home/user/Pradi] is where my log4jExample.java file resides and initially i placed log4j2.xml in [/home/user/Pradi/config] folder. All the log4j2 jars like log4j12-api-2.0-beta3.jar etc are in [/home/user/log4j2/apache-log4j-2.0-beta3-bin] and classpath contains[/home/user/log4j2/apache-log4j-2.0-beta3-bin],[home/user/Pradi/config/l‌​og4j2.xml] and i compiled From Pradi folder as i.e. /home/user/Pradi$ javac log4jExample.java since i mentioned classpath in ~/.bashrc i didn't use -classpath option while compiling. Note : i'm doing all this in ubantu not in eclipse IDE